# Bundle one Python Script + Dependencies using setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py

I already found out how to declare the dependencies of my python script in the setup.py configuration, like

```
install_requires=['html2text', 'pystache']
```

When I do a python setup.py sdist, a .tar.gz is created. If I deflate that one and run python setup.py install, all required libs are installed.

But the python script itself is missing in the distribution.... how do I tell setup.py to include my python files in the distribution?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: sorry for this dumb question :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `py_modules` or `packages` arguments. But seriously, this is all covered [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html).

Comment: thanks for the answer. sometimes, you can't see the wood for the trees.